# Develop iphone version of ipad app developed in Objective C in 2012

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ipad

If I have a project developed in Objective C for ipad years ago (2013 actually) ,Can it be develop or enhance to iphone version using objective C now? Or do I need to develop it from scratch in Swift for iphone n ipad?

Comment: You can still use Objective-C.  Whether you want to enhance the existing code or create new code from scratch is up to you

Comment: In practice you will find this **very difficult**.  Yes, obj-C still "work". But in practice anything from 2012 is so old that you'll simply need to start fresh (it makes no difference what language the ancient version was written in - you'll have to start fresh, realistically.)

Comment: Bundle of thanks for your precious feedback. I left ios development 6,7 years ago. Now im thinking to restart it but lot of things have been changed. I used xib files for each screen at that time. I am thinking to make iPhone version of one of my ipad application. I m little confused if the same technology,logic n other things will work or not? Will Apple approve it or not? Looking forward for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Objective C is a well supported language for iOS. There have been some changes to the language, and lots of changes to Cocoa Touch since then. About all you can't use is SwiftUI.

Comment: Bundle of thanks for your precious feedback. I left ios development 6,7 years ago. Now im thinking to restart it but lot of things have been changed. I used xib files for each screen at that time. I am thinking to make iPhone version of one of my ipad application. I m little confused if the same technology,logic n other things will work or not? Will Apple approve it or not? Looking forward for your valuable feedback.